# Can a C++ class have more than one implicit default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have found an interesting case in C++ behavior that confuses me.
Forewarning, I don't do this in my own code. This is just to understand the standard.

Here I have a class M that has no explicit default constructor. It inherits from a class Base that has an explicit default constructor. When I construct class M like this M() or M{}, it will zero out the member r.
If I construct it without any brackets, the member r is not initialized, but the base class constructor is called (as expected).
What is strange to me is that this behavior seems like the class M has two implicit default constructors now - one that leaves the member r uninitialized but calls all inherited constructors and another that will zero it out.

If the M was a pure POD, then I understand this behavior (default initialization vs unitialized), but here even adding M() = default; will still cause it behave differently with new M() and new M.

Because two compilers do the same thing it does not look like a bug, but what is this feature? It is kind of confusing. Is there a simplified scheme to understand it.

Here is a godbolt link to the code https://godbolt.org/z/9srh48Y5Y
I am doing tricks here to force the classes to be allocated on some garbage filled memory so that the behavior is seen on godbolt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//Base class with default constructor
//explicitly defined
class Base
{
public:
  int k;
  Base() : k(0xF){}
};

//A class with default constructor
//explicitly defined
class C
{
public:
  int z;
  C() : z(13){}
};

//Class M does not have explicitly defined
//default constructor
class M : public Base
{
public:
  int r;
  C c;
  //M() = default;
  //M() {}
};

union Buffer
{
    char bbb[sizeof(M)];
    double ddd;
    long long llll;
};

int main()
{
  //to demonstrate which members are initialized
  //I need to fill the memory with some garbage
  //before using it to construct a class
  Buffer buf1;
  Buffer buf2;
  Buffer buf3;
  std::memset(buf1.bbb, 0xCD, sizeof(Buffer));
  std::memset(buf2.bbb, 0xCD, sizeof(Buffer));
  std::memset(buf3.bbb, 0xCD, sizeof(Buffer));

  M* m1 = new (buf1.bbb) M{};
  M* m2 = new (buf2.bbb) M();
  M* m3 = new (buf3.bbb) M;
  std::cout << m1->k << " "  << m1->c.z << " " << m1->r << std::endl;
  std::cout << m2->k << " "  << m2->c.z << " " << m2->r << std::endl;
  std::cout << m3->k << " "  << m3->c.z << " " << m3->r << std::endl;
}i
```

The output with clang 16 (x86-64):

```
15 13 0
15 13 0
15 13 -842150451
```

GCC does the same.

**EDIT**

Here the second more interesting variant of the code that was discussed in the comments (https://godbolt.org/z/aso8Gz4sh).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//Base class with default constructor
//explicitly defined
class Base
{
public:
  int k;
  Base() : k(0xF){}
};

//A class with default constructor
//explicitly defined
class C
{
public:
  int z1;
  int z2;
  C() : z1(13) {}
};

//Class M does not have explicitly defined
//default constructor
class M : public Base
{
public:
  int r;
  C c;
  //M() = default;
  //M() {}
};

union Buffer
{
    char bbb[sizeof(M)];
    double ddd;
    long long llll;
};

int main()
{
  //to demonstrate which members are initialized
  //I need to fill the memory with some garbage
  //before using it to construct a class
  Buffer buf1;
  Buffer buf2;
  Buffer buf3;
  std::memset(buf1.bbb, 0xCD, sizeof(Buffer));
  std::memset(buf2.bbb, 0xCD, sizeof(Buffer));
  std::memset(buf3.bbb, 0xCD, sizeof(Buffer));

  M* m1 = new (buf1.bbb) M{};
  M* m2 = new (buf2.bbb) M();
  M* m3 = new (buf3.bbb) M;
  std::cout << m1->k << " " << m1->c.z1 << " " << m1->c.z2 << " " << m1->r << std::endl;
  std::cout << m2->k << " " << m2->c.z1 << " " << m2->c.z2 << " " << m2->r << std::endl;
  std::cout << m3->k << " " << m3->c.z1 << " " << m3->c.z2 << " " << m3->r << std::endl;
}
```

clang 16.0 output

```
15 13 -842150451 0
15 13 0 0
15 13 -842150451 -842150451
```

gcc 13.2 output

```
15 13 0 0
15 13 0 0
15 13 -842150451 -842150451
```

Comment: [Default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) vs [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and [value Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: Here is a slightly modified code https://godbolt.org/z/aso8Gz4sh that demonstrates also the difference between zero and value initialization (as @user17732522 mentions in the comments). I've added two variables to C, one of which is left uninitialized in C(), and so now one can see that value initialization makes a different output than zero initialization.

Comment: Oh no, for the case here I see different behavior in gcc 13.2 vs clang 16.0. One has exactly same output for M{} and M() and another has random value for c.z2.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior.  `M` is an *aggregate* since it has no:

- user-declared constructors
- `virtual`, `private` or `protected` base classes
- direct `private` or `protected` data members
- `virtual` member functions
- default member initializers

That means that it follows the *aggregate initialization* rules.

The rules for *aggregate initialization* are essentially as follows:

- If the object is *default initialized*:

  - All base and member sub-objects get *default initialized* as well.  That's what happens when you construct an `M` without any brackets.
- If the object is initialized with a *braced-init-list*:

  - The first N base and member sub-objects of the object get initialized with the parameters passed in the *braced-init-list*.
  - All remaining base and member sub-objects get *value initialized*.  That's what happens when you construct an `M` with empty brackets `M{}`
- If the object is *value initialized*:

  - All base and member sub-objects are *value initialized* as well.  That's what happens when you construct an `M` using empty parenthesis `M()`.

So:

- `new M`: All sub-objects are *default initialized* (which means uninitialized for POD objects)
- `new M{}` or `new M()`: All sub-objects are *value initialized* (which means zero-initialization for POD objects)
- `new M{{}, 10}`: The `M` object's `Base` sub-object is initialized using `{}`, its `r` sub-object is initialized with `10`, and its `c` sub-object is *value initialized*.

Comment: @user17732522 I've tried to check what you were saying  https://godbolt.org/z/aso8Gz4sh. If you switch gcc 13.2 and clang 16.0 you'll see difference in M() vs M{} in one of the compilers. So now it is probably a bug. Which one is right?

Comment: @0kcats Sorry, I shouldn't have deleted my previous comments. Your test is flawed because it is UB to read the uninitialized `z2` in the `{}` case. You cannot actually observe the bits you put into its memory location prior to `new`. `new` "resets" the value to an indeterminate one and reading an indeterminate value always causes UB. `{}` will leave `z2` indeterminate, but `()` won't for the reasons I mentioned in my previous comment. (`r` will be zero-initialized in both cases)

Comment: Short recap of my deleted comments: 1. Subobjects in value-initialization are not value-initialized. Depending on whether there is a deleted/user-provided default constructor value-initialization is either default-initialization or recursive zero-initialization followed by default-initialization. That's different for the example given by @0kcats in the comment above. 2. "_All remaining base and member sub-objects get value initialized._": They get initialized as if by `= {}` which may be e.g. aggregate-initialization instead of value-initialization. (Beware: Rules changed with C++03/C++11.)

Comment: @user17732522 So based on what you say, can I assume that if class has constructors and leaves some members uninitialized, there is no initialization as M() or M{} to make it fill it with zeros for anything that was missed in ctors?

Comment: @0kcats If `M` has a user-provided constructor that is being used, then it is that constructor's responsibility to assure that all members are initialized as desired. Yes, in general there is no initialization form that guarantees full zero-initialization.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with inherited classes you need to know the rules for constructors:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Explanation

If a constructor is defined and applicable it will be called, when inheriting construction of an object starts with the base-class, and at each level from left to right, till at last the constructor of your object is called.

```
#include <iostream>

#define constr(x) x(){ std::cout <<  #x " constructor" << std::endl; }
#define dstr(x) ~x(){ std::cout <<  #x " destructor " << std::endl; }

class base1
{
    public:
    explicit constr(base1);
    dstr(base1);
};

class base2
{
    public:
    constr(base2);
    dstr(base2);
};

class derived1 : public base1, public base2
{
    public:
    constr(derived1);
    dstr(derived1);
};

class derived2 : public base2, public base1
{
};

int main()
{
    derived1 d1;
    std::cout << std::endl << "=================" << std::endl << "now d2" << std::endl;
    derived2 d2;
    std::cout << std::endl << "=================" << std::endl << "and destruction" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

We have 2 base-classes `base1` and `base2` and 2 derived-classes `derived1` and `derived2` and `derived2` does NOT have any user-defined constructors or destructors.
Now when instantiating and object of type `derived1` we will see the contructor-calls to `base1` then `base2` and finally `derived1` and when its livetime ends (end of `main`) we see the destructors called in reverse order of construction.
With `derived2` we see the same thing - the base-class-constructors are called Left-to-right and the destructors in reverse.